# Thunderbird can't find mail server configuration

Tags: debian, ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, thunderbird

I'm having issues when it comes to connecting to my mail server using Thunderbird client. The weird thing is that I can connect to my mail server usign telnet in the client "telnet mail.zumsfresh 25"

[image: Telnet mail testing from the client]
[image: Comprovation mail is received in the mail server]

POSTFIX CONFIGURATION:
[image: Postfix configuration]

Dovecot SSL configuration:
[image: SSL self-signed certificate configuration]

This is the result when I try to connect using Thunderbird with the client. As I said, with the same client I can connect using "telnet mail.zumsfresh.com 25" but the error below appears.
I know it can be the password or username wrong, but I checked and this is the right password and the right username so this error is not possible. I also checked that I have installed Dovecot imapd and Dovecot pop3d and they are.
[image: Checking if Dovecot-imapd and Dovecot-pop3d are installed]
[image: Thunderbird error]

[image: SSL accepting that there is not encryptation.]

[image: Checking password for a very long time]

Comment: please, don't post screenshots of text, but add the text and format is as code. thanks.

Comment: @RoVo I need at least 10 of reputations because inside configuration there are plenty of links so I'm not allowed to post the configuration in plain text. I would highly aprecciate if you can look my configuration even if the only way is trought and img.

Comment: if you format it as code, you don't need any reputation, because the urls are not converted to links.